# Why is that alarm manager is running previously schedule alarm every time when burn the new apk?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I have requirement where i scheduled the different alarm manager for different timings as shown below.

```
private void SetAlarmforFirst(Context context, String value, String PrimaryText) {
        String[] labelLanguage = value.split(":");
        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        Intent downloader = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        downloader.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", PrimaryText);
        PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HomeScreen.this, 0, downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) HomeScreen.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownload);
    }

    private void SetAlarmforSecond(Context context, String value,String PrimaryText) {
        String[] labelLanguage = value.split(":");
        Calendar updateTimeSecond = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTimeSecond.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        updateTimeSecond.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        updateTimeSecond.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
        Intent downloaderSecond = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        downloaderSecond.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", PrimaryText);
        PendingIntent recurringDownloadSecond = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HomeScreen.this, 1, downloaderSecond, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmsSecond = (AlarmManager) HomeScreen.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmsSecond.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTimeSecond.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownloadSecond);
    }

    private void SetAlarmforThird(Context context, String value, String PrimaryText) {
        String[] labelLanguage = value.split(":");
        Calendar updateTimethird = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTimethird.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        updateTimethird.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        updateTimethird.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
        Intent downloaderThird = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        downloaderThird.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", PrimaryText);
        PendingIntent recurringDownloadThird = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HomeScreen.this, 2, downloaderThird, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmsThird = (AlarmManager) HomeScreen.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmsThird.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTimethird.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownloadThird);
    }
```

When i do any changes in the timings for anyone of the alarm manager and run the app again, instead of running the changed alarm manager, it is running the previous ones as well only if the previous alarm manager timings are less than the newly scheduled one.

Could you please let me know where i'm doing wrong.Thank you.

Comment: Because the time is past, and Android runs the Alarms late, using the `better late than never` approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Frank. I didn't you. Could you please elaborate a more?

Comment: Basically, check if the alarm times are past. if so, then re-set their dates by adding one day.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I will check it and let you know.